# about reading files and using tryCatch() in R

Tags: r, try-catch

What I want to do is to read output files and extract some value in files. But, in fact, some files don't exist, so I use tryCatch() in my program to catch those "errors", then my program will return a NA value and continue reading the next file. But when I execute my program, it reports errors("all connections are in use"), I have tried to find answers online, but there is no good answer for my questions. So, if you can solve my problem, please give your advice ! Thank you very much !

```
prop.protec <- 0.5
pat <- read.csv("~/par.csv",header = FALSE) # parameter file
pat <- as.matrix(pat)
tpw <- matrix(NA, nrow = 36, ncol = num.rep) # used to store p-values
num.rep <- 500

for (i in 1:36){
# following are 4 parameters
dis.mod <- pat[i,1]
herit.tot <- pat[i,2]
bin <- pat[i,3]
op <- pat[i,4]

for(reps in 1:num.rep){

tryCatch(
  {
    res.file <- paste("~/z-out-",op, "-", dis.mod, "-",bin,"-",herit.tot,"-",prop.protec,"-",reps, ".extended.qls.res", sep = "")
    res.dat <- read.table(file = res.file, header = TRUE)
    tpw[i,reps] <- res.dat$P_MFQLS
  },
   warning=function(cond) {
   message("Here's the original warning message:")
   message(cond)        
  },
  error = function(e){
   message("Here's the original error message:")
   message(e)} )
   }
  }
```

[image: error message]

Comment: when I  run `res.dat <- read.table(file = res.file, header = TRUE)`, it reports **Error in file(file, "rt") : all connections are in use**. I also try to figure out why it happens, so far, I still have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, a very simple and wonderful answer, we just need to add `closeAllConnections()` at the end of inner loop. That works very well ! I have spent much time on it, when I know this answer and succeed, I believe you can understand my feeling.